# jQuery fade in/out two divs at a time, looping and repeating

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, repeat

I'm using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Wordpress with the [Repeater Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) activated to give a client the ability to add as many testimonials as they want. The testimonials are each displayed inside a `.quote` div on the front-end. However, I only want two `.quote` divs to be displayed at a time (in consecutive order), and fade in/out two at at time.

Like this:

**Page loads**: quotes 1 & 2 are shown.
**7 seconds go by**: quotes 3 & 4 are shown. 
**Another 7 seconds go by**: quotes 5 & 6 are shown. Repeat, etc, not dependent on the amount of quotes there are (there could be 20, 5, 18, etc.) and once the last two `.quote` divs are reached, it will restart from the beginning.

I've thrown together a super rudimentary and terrible bit of code to ***try*** and illustrate my point here: http://jsfiddle.net/9kg6L/

I'm sure there's an easy solution for this, but I'm still a newbie writing jQuery, so I hope to learn from this little experience :)

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what your question is. Is there an issue with the code in your jsFiddle you're trying to fix or are you trying to replicate that functionality elsewhere?  EDIT: Ah I guess you're trying to make it generic so it works regardless of how many quotes you have and repeats?

Comment: Yeah, I need it to be more generic and also repeat from the beginning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
var quotes = $('#container .quote');

function cycleQuotes () {
    var current = quotes.filter(".active"), next;
    if (current.length == 0 || (next = current.next().next()).length == 0 ) {
        // first iteration or last, select first two
        next = quotes.slice(0,2);
    }
    current.removeClass('active').fadeOut(400).promise().done(function(){
        next.addClass('active').fadeIn(); 
    });
    setTimeout(cycleQuotes,7*1000);
}
cycleQuotes();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kg6L/1/

It could probably be improved to instead of showing only the last one if there's an odd number, showing the last + first, then cycling through from then on being one off.

Answer (score 1):

somwhat near .

```
var interval=2000;
var j=4
for(var i=2;i<50;i++){  

setTimeout(function() {
    quote.slice(i,j).fadeOut();
}, interval);
interval=interval+2000;
      j=j+2;
      i++;
}
```

you fix it